# Is the no of photons related to frequency? And how the distribution of electromagnetic radiations was explained?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, thermal-radiation

Am studying blackbody radiation and my  school book says literally :"As frequency increases, the energy of each photon increases but the no of photons decreases that's why the density of electromagnetic radiation goes down (low densities is low wavelengths)

Comment: At high frequencies, the probability of a photon state being occupied goes down as exp$(-hf/kT)$. So the book is correct (but by itself a sentence like this is a bit cryptic).

Comment: have a look at the black body  curves here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_body.svg

Comment: Or this one, intensity as a function of frequency: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PlankLawOmega.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the frequency increases, the energy increases, that is correct as
$$ E= nhν  $$

where E is energy, n is number of photons, ν is the frequency and h is Planck's constant.

Number of photons are not related to frequency in that way. But if the energy of the light beam remains constant then the number of photons should decrease (as energy is constant and energy of each photon increases) so the density of electromagnetic radiation decreases ( photons per unit area).

Low density does not mean low wavelength. Wavelength depends only on frequency of the photon (and speed of light which is constant).
It can be found by the relation

$$ λ = \frac {c}{ν} $$

λ is the wavelength, c is speed of light.

Comment: I believe the book is referring to the distribution of photons emitted by a blackbody, so when it says "the number of photons", it means "the number of photons emitted with that frequency"

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted the question.